# Why doesn't pattern substitution work from a single variable?

Tags: bash, variable

Please see the below session transcript:

```bsh
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp/
$ touch file{1..5}
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
$ SRC=file; TGT=ram
$ for f in file* ; do mv $f ${f/$SRC/$TGT} ; done
$ ls
ram1  ram2  ram3  ram4  ram5
$ PAT=ram/file
$ for f in ram* ; do mv $f ${f/$PAT} ; done
mv: 'ram1' and 'ram1' are the same file
mv: 'ram2' and 'ram2' are the same file
mv: 'ram3' and 'ram3' are the same file
mv: 'ram4' and 'ram4' are the same file
mv: 'ram5' and 'ram5' are the same file
```

Why does the pattern substitution work if I provide `SRC` and `TGT` as separate variables and not if I provide them as a single variable `PAT`?

My understanding is that substitutions are processed inside out, and so the string within the outer set of braces i.e. `f/$SRC/$TGT` or `f/$PAT` should be equally processed to `f/file/ram` or `f/ram/file`, which is then again processed to give the actual new file name. But apparently this is not done so…

I'm using Bash 4.4.18 on Kubuntu Bionic LTS with latest updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **`${parameter/pattern/string}`**
>   The `pattern` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. [...] If `string` is null, matches of `pattern` are deleted
>   and the `/` following pattern may be omitted.

So, the process isn't such that the pattern and replacement are determined after expansion. Instead, first the pattern and replacement components are identified, and *then* they're expanded. In `${f/$PAT}`, the entirety of `$PAT` becomes the pattern, and the replacement is empty.

Comment: You can use `eval` to work around that: `eval "mv \$f \${f/$PAT}"`. Would be great to include this (or other possible solutions) in your answer.

Comment: @filbranden Using `eval` safely is tricky enough that I'd rather not. This is pretty much a non-problem - I don't see any good reason why anyone would want to do this. Even if, for some weird reason, somebody had `pattern/string` in a variable, splitting those out into separate variables is easy enough that there's no good reason to use `eval` either.