# Using a variable as pattern for case command

Tags: bash, case

So this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

action_list='list|add|rem'

while true; do
        echo "Actions include: list - show list
                                add - add item to list
                                rem - remove item from list"
        read -p "Input action: " action_var

        case $action_var in
                ${action_list} ) echo "Option $action_var is valid";;
                *) echo "Option $action_var is INVALID";;
        esac

        echo $action_var
done
```

What I want is to use the case command such that, in the future if I add more options, I don't need to hardcode them in, I can just use the "action_list" variable.

But the `${action_list} )` construct does not work.
Now I tried hardcoding it like `list|add|rem)...` and it works.

Why wouldn't a variable work in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Checking the docs:

> #### [`case`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case)
>
> The syntax of the case command is:
>
> ```
>  case word in
>     [ [(] pattern [| pattern]…) command-list ;;]… esac
> ```
>
> [...] Each *pattern* undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion,
>   command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

What happens is that parameter expansion takes place *after* the patterns have been identified (using the `|` separator). A `|` from an expansion then is just the plain `|` character and not a pattern separator. (Similar reasoning as in [another answer from me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523281/70524).)

Comment: So then how would I do what I want to do here?

Comment: @user361323 you could use the `[[` extended test and regular expression matching (`if [[ $action_var =~ $action_list ]]; then ...`). Or one of the options in [How do I test if an item is in a bash array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177138/70524)

Comment: But in this case if `$action_var=do` and `$action_list="sum drop dont etc"` it would be matched, no? So I'd have to add some magic and add `$action_var="^whatever_the_var_is$"` right?

Comment: Or one of the options in [How do I test if an item is in a bash array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177138/70524), instead of forcing an array into a string and trying to test for inclusion in that.

Comment: I also thought of using a loop, but wouldn't that create a lot of overhead? Let's say an extreme case, what if there are 2 million options in `$action_list` and the one that would match `$action_var` is at the end of the list, it'd have to iterate through all of them. The other answers (associative arrays) are a bit more complex and I need to study them a bit more.

Comment: If you have 2 million (or even 2 hundred) actions, something somewhere has gone horribly wrong and Cthulhu has risen.

Comment: Hehe, there might be a possibility because the larger scope of this project is a text based game of sorts. Of course, 2m is greatly exaggerated, even 200 is pretty far fetched.

Comment: @user361323, if you actually had to even consider 2 million anything, you should already be as far as possible from any shell scripts... 2 thousand would already be a point where you probably should be running away.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only two responses, I don’t think `case` is the right solution here. Many ways to go about this; I would do something like this:

```
action_list="list|add|remove|foo|bar"
if grep -qE "^(${action_list})$" <<< "${action_var}" ; then
  echo valid
else
  echo not valid ${action_var}
fi
```

If you are using bash, or a shell with similar variable expansion, this might be preferable for readability of the list variable:

```
action_list="list add remove foo bar"
if grep -qE "^(${action_list// /|})$" <<< "${action_var}" ; then
  echo valid
else
  echo not valid ${action_var}
fi
```